# Visual Studio 2013: Define colors for certain code lines / hide code automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, visual-studio-2013

I have an Windows Forms Window and a Console Window for Debugging output of my application (C#). Now I want to distinguish between the output code (`Console.WriteLine("");` or `Console.*`) and the rest.
Is there an opportunity to hide or color the code automatically?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the theme to **DARK**.You can distinguish the code by color.

**Tools->Option->Environment->General->Color Theme-> Dark**

**Tools->Option->Environment->Font and Colors**

number of formatting settings, including

- Fonts and Colors
- Indenting
- Spacing
- Braces
- Line Wrapping

Comment: no, that is not what I want to do. I want to have the whole line in a specific color, like a comment.

Comment: @user3621741 look the updated code.it will help You to customize your needs.

Comment: ah OK, but how can I change the color for ONE specific method, like `Console.WriteLine("");`?